# Is it known whether the Fermi-Hubbard ground state can be prepared efficiently or not?

Tags: resource-request, complexity-theory, state-preparation, many-body-systems

Naturally, in general, ground state preparation is QMA-complete. There exists [a paper by Andrew Childs, David Gosset & Zak Webb](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-43948-7_26), which shows that ground state preparation for the Bose-Hubbard model is QMA-complete.

However, **is it known what the complexity of ground state preparation for the Fermi-Hubbard model is?** I could not find this in the literature directly, does this follow trivially from a general result which I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

In [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys1370), Schuch and Verstraete determined the computational complexity of finding the ground state of the Fermi-Hubbard model, showing that it is among the hardest problems in the complexity class QMA, Quantum Merlin Arthur.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! (will upvote as soon as I have the reputation) But if I understand correctly, strictly speaking, this completeness proof works only for the Fermi-Hubbard Hamiltonian with local magnetic fields $H_{\mathrm{Hubb}}=-t \sum_{\langle i, j\rangle, s} a_{i, s}^{\dagger} a_{j, s}+U \sum_i n_{i, \uparrow} n_{i, \downarrow}-\sum_i \boldsymbol{\sigma}_i \cdot \mathbf{B}_i$ - so this doesn't quite proof that an efficient ground state preparation for the Fermi-Hubbard model without magnetic fields is impossible, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, indeed the proof by Schuch and Verstraete does include the coupling of local magnetic fields to the spin degrees of freedom. Moreover, the proof involves going from the spin-1/2 Heisenberg model to the Fermi-Hubbard model, which is only strictly valid at half-filling in the limit $U/t \to \infty$, since charge fluctuations are frozen. I have looked for other papers discussing the complexity class of the Fermi-Hubbard model, but could not find any that were more relevant than this one.

Comment: Let me also note that, even if the Fermi-Hubbard model is in the QMA class, it does not mean it is impossible to achieve quantum advantage in the determination of its ground state properties relative to state-of-the-art numerical methods (e.g., PEPS-based Corner Transfer Matrix, Quantum Monte Carlo) implemented on conventional hardware for system sizes of the order of $30-50$ sites in two-dimensional lattices. It simply means that the resources required to scale up the simulations grow exponentially with the number of electrons.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the magnetic field loophole appears to be closed, see this (open-access) https://journals.aps.org/prxquantum/abstract/10.1103/PRXQuantum.3.020322

Comment: @Dr.T.Q.Bit thank you, this is indeed exactly what I was looking for! In case you prefer to turn this into an answer, I am very happy to mark it as accepted.